# Java : need explanation about Graphics

Tags: java, swing, graphics

I would like to know a little more about Graphics and how to use it.

I have this class :

```
public class Rectangle 
{
    private int x, y, length, width;
    // constructor, getters and setters

    public void drawItself(Graphics g)
    {
        g.drawRect(x, y, length, width);
    }
}
```

And a very simple frame like this :

```
public class LittleFrame extends JFrame 
{
    Rectangle rec = new Rectangle(30,30,200,100);      

    public LittleFrame()
    {
        this.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
        this.setSize(600,400);
        this.setVisible(true);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        new LittleFrame();
    }
}
```

What I simply want to do is to add this rectangle into my LittleFrame's container. But I have no idea of how to do it.

Comment: I would suggest you take a look at [Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/), [Graphics 2D](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/index.html) and [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest you create an extra class that extends `JPanel` like the one below:

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class GraphicsPanel extends JPanel {

    private List<Rectangle> rectangles = new ArrayList<Rectangle>();

    public void addRectangle(Rectangle rectangle) {
        rectangles.add(rectangle);
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        for (Rectangle rectangle : rectangles) {
            rectangle.drawItself(g);
        }
    }
}
```

Then, in your `LittleFrame` class, you will need to add this new panel to your frame content pane and add your `Rectangle` to the list of rectangles to be painted. At the end of the `LittleFrame` constructor, add:

```
GraphicsPanel panel = new GraphicsPanel();
panel.addRectangle(rec);
getContentPane().add(panel);
```

Comment: @Rob Another option is to replace your Rectangle class with `JPanel`'s on which you set a "backgroundColor" and you add those `JPanel`'s to your `LittleFrame`. For the positionning and size of the `JPanel`'s, use an appropriate `LayoutManager`. This solution is much more in the "Swing"-way

Comment: Unless he wants to draw circles next.